# insert matrix into the center of another matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there any fast and simple way to insert a small matrix into the center (or any other x,y index) of another, biger matrix using numpy or scipy?
That is, say I have matrix

```
A = [1 2]
    [3 4]
```

and matrix

```
B =   [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I want to insert A into the center of B as so:

```
C =   [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 1 2 0 0]  
      [0 0 3 4 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]  
      [0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use numpy's slice notation.

```
nb = B.shape[0]
na = A.shape[0]
lower = (nb) // 2 - (na // 2)
upper = (nb // 2) + (na // 2)
B[lower:upper, lower:upper] = A
```

Comment: This works exactly as it should, as long as one would be wary of the dimensions of the would-be-inserted matrix.